# Limit concurrent connections to ASP.NET Web Api application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, limit

I'm looking for a way to limit the maximum number of concurrent connections to a ASP.NET MVC4 Web Api application, preferably in the application itself. Like in the web.config or some property which can be dynamically set.

The Web application makes use of another application which is limited to a number of open slots. Once these slots are all taken, any request (POST) will pretty much fail, in the sense that the resource being created will be empty.

Is it possible to configure the limit in the application itself using existing functionality in ASP.NET or do I have to write this myself? Configuring it in IIS is an option, but more as a last resort.

Thank you.